# Getting old value on page load instead of the recent value: dash, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, callback, plotly-dash

How can I force dash to take latest stored value in a file on page load?
I can set a value to a database(a file), then as I use callbacks, this value is shown on dashboard. Until here everything is fine.
The problem is when I refresh the page then I got the old(previous) value shown instead. Do you, please, have any suggestions to fix that?

```
metric(
            id="selected_price",
            value=get_price(),
        ),

dmc.TextInput(
            id="price",
            value=get_price(),
         ),
dmc.Button("Apply", id="apply_button"),
```

When you press the button, the value got saved in the file and showed on screen(`selected_price`).

```
@callback(
    Output("selected_price", "value"),
    Input("apply_button", "n_clicks"),
    State("price", "value"),
)
def update_price(n_clicks, value):
    if n_clicks:
        set_price(price=float(value))
    return get_price()
```

Comment: What kind of component is returned by `metric()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [persistence](https://dash.plotly.com/persistence), eg. :

```py
dmc.TextInput(
            id="price",
            placeholder=get_price(), # instead of value (just a suggestion)
            persistence=True
         )
```

It will use [`dcc.Store`](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/store) components and use them as proxies for getting/setting data, which you could also do manually.